# PayPal classical API with reoccuring payment in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am working on `Laravel 4.2` project. The project is about to provide the Video services to the dedicated customers.

The client wants to use `PayPal` payment gateway and I have never done this before. He has provided me a `Personal` and a `Business` account with `Classical API` credentials and signature.

The project requirement is once user sign-up, he will be charged certain amount (let us say $10 every month). For payment he must **NOT** be redirected to `PayPal site` that means everything should be done using my website only. Also we will **NOT** store any credit card details of the user and still the Payment should be done OR **renewed automatically** every month.

If user wants to turn of the the auto renewal of payment, he can.

I am not sure how to do this using `PayPal classical API`. Although I have downloaded the `Omnipay/Omnipay` package from `git-hub`, they asks there is no method to store the user's credit card details in `PayPal Vault` using this also to have a `cron job` for auto renewal. Since I don't want to store the credit card details, I am not sure how to do all this.

Please help me or guide me to do so. Is there any sample or example?

Comment: Experts available here? Is it that difficult to be integrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to take credit cards directly like you're asking you'll need to sign up with PayPal [Payments Pro](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-pro), which is $30/mo.  Then you'll need to add the recurring billing feature to that, which is another $30/mo.

If that's not a problem, then after getting those things approved and active on your account, you would use the [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/) API to create the subscription profiles.

This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) is [available on Packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/angelleye/paypal-php-library) and works with Composer, so it works wonderfully in Laravel.

The [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile sample](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/dev/samples/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.php) is functional as-is (although, as I look at it now you'll need to update the expiration date of the credit card) so you would just need to replace all of the static data with your own dynamic data.

The [template file](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library/blob/dev/templates/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile.php) is the same thing but it's completely empty and ready for you to populate with your own data.

Using that SDK you can have the profile creation working within minutes, so it's just a matter of having Pro w/ Recurring Payments enabled on your account.

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting the answer. Can I get any example or sample codes for the same to set up all this?

Comment: The samples are included in the SDK and I provided a link directly to the sample you would be using.  If you run that sample as-is it will create a profile.  All you need to do is setup a form to gather your customer data and populate the sample with that data instead of the static sample data it's using now.  Or you can start with the template which is already empty.

Comment: How can I use the config.php and autoload.php? Where can I include them as I am using Laravel 4.2, I am getting error if I use require_once or File::require_once statement inside the controller where I want to make the code to use PayPal sdk.

Comment: Adding the SDK to your composer.json that was created when you generated your Laravel project (assuming you used artisan to create it) should handle getting the library loaded and ready for use within your Laravel project.  For the config file, it's recommended that you setup environment variables and us those within the config at /app/config/paypal.php.  You can see a [sample of that here](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-glass/blob/master/app/config/paypal.php).  Check [Laravel's config docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration) for info on setting up env vars.

Comment: By the way, that sample of the PayPal config is part of a project I'm calling PayPal Glass where I'm basically replicating the PayPal UI in Laravel using my class library to show off how it can do everything you need with PayPal.  You might want to pull that whole project and take a look at it.

Comment: Does it require to use SetExpressCheckout first before creating a reoccuring profile using CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile? Because CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile requires token that returned from either SetExpressCheckout or SetCustomerBillingAgreement, both of these methods required return url and cancel url. The confusion is what should I specifiy in return or cancel url when I am not going to redirect user to PayPal? I think it should only be required if User redirected to the PayPal.

Comment: The token is only required in CRPP if you're using Express Checkout.  If you want to use a credit card directly you would use nothing but CRPP and you would not need to provide a token or redirect/cancel URLs.

Comment: OK got it. I have created a CRPP without token and it works. But it seems that it is not starting charging from today, but it may start charging from next cycle. I want the customer start paying from today and then the profile should charge automatically from next billing cycle. In short, if I create profile today, I must be get paid from the customer from today and it should recurred every month. Is it possible? Another question, creating recurring profile will store the credit card details automatically in PayPal vault? If no, what should I do to store it in vault?

Comment: Sorry. I got the documentation in https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/ and according to it I can specify a non-recurring inital amount while creating a profile. :) Great.. Now, please let me know if I would required to store the credit card information of Buyers in PayPal vault or recurring profile will automatically do it?

Comment: The recurring profile handles that for you.  As for the first payment, if you set the start date of the profile to "today" then the first payment would come through that first day (although maybe not immediately.)  If you use initial amount to process the first day's payment then you'll want to set the start date of the profile to 1 month later (or week, quarter, etc.)

Comment: OK. Got it. By the way, whenever I am creating profile, the profile status I found in response is "PendingProfile" and using your GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails page if I get the profile details then after some time it gets status "active", now is there any technique that I may get the notification about such changes? Also for recurring payments? For example, I've set the recurring profile starts from today and billing cycle is one month then after one month if payment is done, will I get any notification from PayPal?

Comment: Yes, you will get email notifications.  If you want to automate things in code based on when transactions occur or a profile status changes you can use [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

Comment: I have set the Instant Payment Notification and its listener. I think, it is not notifying me when profile updated to "Active" from "PendingProfile". Have you any idea about it? Yes for Payments it's working well. :). Can I have some notification for manage profile also?

Comment: Also can I update the billing cycle dates in recurring profile? Suppose my profile has billing cycle set from the 1st date of month to the last date of month and payment will be recurred on 1st date of next month, but now I want to update the cycle from 5th of current month to 4th of next month. Is it possible?

Comment: Oh my god !!! Its txn_type :) Got it.. Thanks. I will paste all my codes in question with edit that the other people who wants to do the same integration should not suffer anymore.

Comment: But Also can I update the billing cycle dates in recurring profile? As I mentioned in my 2nd last comment above?

Comment: Can you please let me know if you have any idea?